# How to cut a rectangular patch from an object?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, object-mode

I have an object in which a model is wearing a shirt. I need to cut an object from the front of the shirt such that the shape is rectangular and curved like the surface of the shirt like seen below:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: have you tried using the knife tool?

Comment: I tried with the knife tool but only vertices are getting cut and not the entire object selection area(edges/face) as seen here- https://imgur.com/a/FrWTnRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways of doing this: duplicate the mesh and using the knife tool, box selecting and removing the rest, etc.

For the least destructive, I'd recommend duplicating and using the boolean modifier. Here's an example with Suzanne, one with the modifier and one with the modifier applied (and removed a couple of the back vertices):

[image: boolean modifier with intersection on Suzanne monkey]